# Kendo Number Formattig For unwanted zeros

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, formatting

I am looking to filter my kendo.toString to knock off the unwanted zeros leaving a two decimal place minimum and 4 decimal place maximum. for example...

- 25.7670 will render as 25.767
- 250 will render as 250.00
- 25.7080 will render as 25.708
- 25.000 will render as 25.00

my actual markup is

```
<li><label>Flagfall:</label>$#= (Flagfall == null) ? '0.00' : kendo.toString(Flagfall, "n4") #</li>
```

Comment: You can create a global function to handle this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested my proposal against the examples you've given. I've tested it against numbers. If you have a string containing a number then just use it like:

```
var result = convert(+string);
```

Anyways, here's the solution:

```
var x = 25.000;
function convert(value) {
    let [a, b] = ('' + value).split(/\./);
    b = b? b.replace(/([0-9]{2}[1-9]*9+)/, '$1') : '00';
    return a + '.' + b;
}
console.log(convert(25.7670));
console.log(convert(250));
console.log(convert(25.7080));
console.log(convert(25.000)); // same as 25, honestly
```

The function returns a string. If you want it to be number, just put + before it, like:

```
var result = +convert(your_number_here);
```

Or if you prefer/need old Javascript version:

```
function convert(value) {
    var array = ('' + value).split(/\./);
    var a = array[0];
    var b = array[1];
    b = b? b.replace(/([0-9]{2}[1-9]*9+)/, '$1') : '00';
    return a + '.' + b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your format string can be changed to be `kendo.toString(Flagfall, "#.00##")`. The `0` placeholders denote required slots to be filled, whereas the `#` placeholders denote the optional positions. Kendo seems to handle this nicely:

```js
var numbers = [42, 42.0, 0, 0.01, 0.0003, 5.2, 4.12351, 4.12355],
  template = "kendo.toString(num, '#.00##')"
  tpl = kendo.template("Number: #= num #\t- #= " + template.replace(/#/g, "\\\\#") + "#  \t Formatted\n"),
  $text = $("#text");

numbers.forEach(function(num) {
  $text.val($text.val() + tpl({
    num: num
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="text" style="height: 10em; width: 30em;"></textarea>
```

If you were using the [Kendo Numeric Textbox](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/numerictextbox), you can use the [format string](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/numerictextbox#configuration-format) combined with the [decimals](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/numerictextbox#configuration-decimals) property.

```js
$("#numerictextbox").kendoNumericTextBox({
  format: "#.00##",
  decimals: 4
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<input id="numerictextbox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom javascript function like

```
var isInt = function(n) { return parseInt(n) === n };

function format(num){
  if(isInt(num)){
    return Number(num).toFixed(2);
  }else{
    return Number(num).toFixed(3);
  }
}

console.log(format(25.7670));
```

to achieve this.

Comment: Would this not fix to 2 decimal places if the number is an integer or 3 decimal places all other times? Maybe giving 25.01 into 25.010 instead of 25.01